# Custom UIView for an UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller, swift-protocols

I use code to create the view (with subviews) for `UIViewController`'s this is how I do it:

1. override `loadView()`

   ```
   class MYViewController: UIViewController {

   var myView: MyView! { return self.view as MyView }

      override func loadView() {
         view = MyView() 
      }
   }
   ```

and here is how I create my custom view:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    // MARK: Initialization

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        addSubviews()
        setupLayout()
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    // MARK: Build View hierarchy

    func addSubviews(){
        // add subviews
    }

    func setupLayout(){
        // Autolayout
    }

    // lazy load views
}
```

I do this for all my View Controllers and I am looking for more elegant way, because this process is repetitive, so is there any solution for make that generic for example, create a super abstract class, or create an extension for UIViewController and UIView, Protocols ? I am new for swift and I think that Swift can have a better elegant solution with it's modern patterns

Comment: Wha'ts the main problem you're trying to solve here? Repetitive code? If that's the case why not just make the ViewController and View classes abstract classes that you can then extend?

Comment: Try custom delegate protocol for this custom View

Comment: Somehow I feel you should use storyboards/xibs more. It's very rare that I have to create custom views. Why bother with subviews and layout settings in code when you can do it faster and more effectively in a visual editor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are wanting to create many different controllers with custom view classes my recommended solution would be along these lines:

First implement a custom view subclass the way you want to be able to use it, here I have used the one you had in your question. You can then subclass this anywhere you need it and just override the relevant methods.

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    // MARK: Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubviews()
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addSubviews()
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    // MARK: Build View hierarchy

    func addSubviews(){
        // add subviews
    }

    func setupLayout(){
        // Autolayout
    }

}
```

Then create a generic custom view controller that allows specification of a class as a generic parameter so that you can easily create a controller with a custom view class.

```
class CustomViewController<T: CustomView>: UIViewController {

    var customView: T! { return view as! T }

    override func loadView() {
        view = T()
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

}
```

Then if you wanted to define a new custom view and create a controller that uses it you can simply:

```
class AnotherCustomView: CustomView { /* Override methods */ }

...

let controller = CustomViewController<AnotherCustomView>()
```

Boom!

If you wanted you could even typealias this new controller type to make it even more elegant:

```
class AnotherCustomView: CustomView { /* Override methods */ }

...

typealias AnotherCustomViewController = CustomViewController<AnotherCustomView>
let controller = AnotherCustomViewController()
```